# List of Lists in dataframe, need to access a single value for all

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with lists in the cells.

```
player1 player2 player3
0   ['PF/C', 'DeMarcus Cousins', 11000] ['PG', 'John Wall', 10700]  ['SF', 'LeBron James', 10600]
1   ['PF/C', 'DeMarcus Cousins', 11000] ['PG', 'John Wall', 10700]  ['PG/SF', 'Giannis Antetokounmpo', 10200]
2   ['PF/C', 'DeMarcus Cousins', 11000] ['PG', 'John Wall', 10700]  ['PG', 'Isaiah Thomas', 10100]
3   ['PF/C', 'DeMarcus Cousins', 11000] ['PG', 'John Wall', 10700]  ['PG', 'Stephen Curry', 10000]
```

For each row, I want to get the int (the players salary) for all 3 listed players in a row and add them up into a new column - df['total salary'].  I can loop through and turn each row_x, column_y into a list, select the salary, store it, then do the same thing for the other two players.  Then store the sum of the salaries back into the dataframe.  But I know that isn't pythonic.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: thanks for making it look pretty @MaxU !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df['total_salary'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['player1'][2] + \
                                        x['player2'][2] + \
                                        x['player3'][2],
                              axis=1)
```

That said, I would like to put in a vote for your splitting each of those lists into separate columns, as that fits my general definition for being more pandas like.

Comment: You're the best! Around! Nothing's gonna ever keep you down!  Thank you sir! you are the bee's knees